# Unable to load library from the current folder in Python

Tags: python, shared-libraries, ctypes

I have very straight forward code:

```
import ctypes
import os
dll_name = "./mylib.so"
print ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(os.path.abspath(dll_name))
```

Both myprog.py and mylib.so are in the same folder:

```
me@host:~/test $ pwd
/home/me/test
me@host:~/test $ ls -a
.   myprog.py       mylib.so
```

Library is loadble:

```
me@host:~/test $ readelf -h mylib.so
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x0
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          385780 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000000, Version5 EABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         7
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         23
  Section header string table index: 22
```

But I am still not able to load the library

```
me@host:~/test $ python myprog.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myprog.py", line 4, in <module>
    print ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(os.path.abspath(dll_name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 440, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 362, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /home/me/test/mylib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From my research the most logical error is there is a dependent module found within

```
 __init__ self.handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
```

that is not within the same folder as your active DIR. 
The only other possibility I can think of is `self._name` is a string variable that is passed a name of a file that is not found in the active DIR.

Also, confirm that `/home/me/test/mylib.so` is a true directory, I only mention this because `.so` would describe a file type. so it may be that the file you are looking for is a different type of file. All of these instances are something you want to check are accurate when receiving this type of error.

Comment: i've validated dependencies. all in place (except one, which for some reason i was unable to find with find_library, so i have created link to it, and now it is ok). another thing that i've validated is target CPU name and arch. also here it looks good.

Comment: so your program is working ok now? or did i misunderstand you.

Comment: no, it does not. all i said is that dependencies and CPU target are ok

Comment: have you checked the last bit i entered in there about the `.so` being a file type and ensuring the same is found within the directory

Comment: this is peculiar, allow me to do some more research and I will post again. This is interesting! in the mean time please check all your dependencies... this includes all dependencies inside your imported modules as well. So you will need to go into your library and find the "LoadLibrary" module and check the dependencies found in there.. if you are moving files around inside python directories you may unintentionally remove a dependency from its proper directory

Comment: It looks like a 32-bit library. Are you on a 32-bit machine?

Comment: Curious, is this a file you have shared through another computer and are attempting to access it from a separate system?